# $30\%$ students fail in Mathematics every year. If this year $500$ students take final exam, $P(145 \leq X \leq 400) = ?$.

Tags: probability, random-variables

It is given that $30\%$  students fail in Mathematics every year. If this year $500$ students take final exam then find $P(145 \leq X \leq 400)$. Here $X$ denotes the number of students fail in Maths.

Can anyone please help me with  this problem?

My Attempt: $30%$  of $500$  is $150$. So $P(145 \leq X \leq 400)=1$ as $145 \leq X=150 \leq 400$. I know this is wrong. Can anyone please explain why it is wrong ?

Comment: I totally agree the question is posed somewhat vaguely. Let's see it this way: Assume that the chance that any individual student fails is $30$%. Assume further more that each student's outcome is independent from one another. From this data you can explicitly write down the chance that $k$ students fail if $n$ students take the exam (the underlying distribution is a binomial distribution). 

From here there are two routes. Either you calculate the result explicitly via the binomial distribution or you approximate by some theory that you have covered.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $n=500$ is large enough you can use CLT and gaussian approx to find the result. In your class have you already studied the "continuity correction factor"?

Here is the solution using the correction factor

$$\mathbb{P}[145\leq X\leq 400]=\Phi\left(\frac{400.5-150}{\sqrt{500\times0.7\times0.3} }\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{144.5-150}{\sqrt{500\times0.7\times0.3} }\right)=$$

$$=\Phi(24.45)-\Phi(-0.54)=1-0.2957\approx70.43\%$$

---

consider that the exact result using the binomial (and a calculator) is $\approx 70.265\%$